# "Include in project" option missing in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I've created an Asp.Net core project in VS 2015 Update 3 and added react using npm. When I tried to include "node_modules" folder into project, I couldn't find "Include in project" option in context menu. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue. And now that you mention it, it does seem to be happening since Update 3.

Answer (score 0):

This is one helluva way of doing it but I got it to work.

I simply created another project (I had a basic web-api project) and copied the "node_modules" directory into that project.  It's my understanding the "include in project" DOES show up for other project types so I used my web api project and it worked.

Then after including it I right-clicked the project file and did an 'Unload Project.'  After unloading the project you can then "edit" the project also using the context menu.  All I did was look for the "Item Group" having all the "node" stuff.  I took that whole group of xml entries from the project definition and cut/pasted into notepad.

Then closed down the project and went into my Angular2 project.  I unloaded that project as I did with webapi and again went into edit mode.  I then copied the contents of the "Item Group" into the Angular2 project.  I saved, then reloaded the project.  You can then see the node_modules directory (not in ghost mode as it was originally).  I restored packages and they all appeared as 'installed.'

I still got a warning about npm not being installed but I ran the project and it worked.  FWIW until this gets fixed.  Agree it's a hack job at best!